# @Size annotation is not working for the validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, annotations

I am trying to validate the size of the username variable but when I entered the input it was not validating the `size` of the `name`, also other validation annotations(`@Email`, `@NotBlank`, etc) are not working.

Following is part of my code:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Component
public class UserDto {     
    
    private int userId;
    
    @Size(min=3, max=15, message = "invalid username !")
    private String name;
    
    @Email(message = "invalid email !")
    //@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9._]+@([-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,5}$", message = "invalid email !")
    @NotBlank(message = "email is required !")
    private String email;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "password is required !")
    private String password;
    
    @Size(min=2, max=6, message = "invalid gender !")
    private String gender;
```

This is my "user controller" which takes the input. Following is the part of my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Validated
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
      
                                //create
    @PostMapping     
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto){
        UserDto userDto1 = userService.createUser(userDto); 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userDto1, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Following is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lcwd.electronic.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>ElectronicStore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ElectronicStore</name>
    <description>backend for electronic strore</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

i was using `javax` then i tried `jakarta` , then it worked
so use `jakarta` instead of `javax`

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
```

=> this is working for me with `jakarta` but i dont know why it is not working with `javax`, so if someone know the reason of this please let me know.

Comment: Just remove the `javax.validation` dependency from your `pom.xml` and use the `spring-boot-starter-validation` only. If you have old java classes replace import statements (as you did).

Comment: `javax.validation` package is for older Spring versions. `jakarta.validation` is the current one.